# Is it possible to use my Pokemon Ruby save file from the online flash version on an emulated version?

Tags: android, pokemon-series, emulation, flash

I played a game on the website en.gamslol.net which has flash games to play. I saved my game as a .sav file which worked fine on the website. The game has now been removed but I have my save file which is 67kb. Is it possible to use this file for the same game on PC or android and if so, how?

Comment: Depends entirely on the game.

Comment: Was not aware of that. It was Pokemon Ruby. Are .sav files "married" to a single instance of a flash game?

Comment: I have a feeling you have your terms confused. By "flash games" do you mean Game Boy Advance games emulated on the Internet?

Comment: Correct, that's what I mean. Not a downloaded ROM but simply on the Internet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, a save file is not the game.

The save file is the data of where *you* are in the game and what *you* have done in the game. Not the game data. You need the original game to load a save file.

After all, it makes no sense to say "You are on earth" (save file) without knowing that earth exists and that it is a planet (game).

Comment: So the .sav file then only pertains to the specific online/Flash game and not a downloaded ROM of the same game correct?

Comment: Yes, given the size of the file it is not a full game.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question being asked. The asker never confused the save file for something that could be played _on its own_.

Comment: Yes the .sav file is quite small so I didn't expect that to be the game. I have thought it may work on VBA but I'm wondering since there are only options for 64kb amd 128kb flash .sav imports if it simply won't work with mine.

Comment: Jcraft153, that's right. Basically im asking is the .sav file I have from the flash/online version of the game locked or "married" to only that specific flash version of the game and not usable with a GBA ROM of the same game?  Apologizies if I'm mixing up terms

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can,

normally an emulator is splitted in three parts:

1. the emulator: the program which is used to simulate(or emulate) the
   hardware of the gameboy (as example the "virtual boy")
2. the rom: this is the game which is contained on the cartridge. It
   can be downloaded from various sites in the web. Or be copyd by your
   personal rom dealer.
3. the savegame: an emulator save this file as an *.sav file

If your save file is such a file you can downloade the pokemon ruby rom file (if i remember right it shoud be a *.vba file) an use it with an gameboy advance emulator.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: This assumes that the game boy emulator uses the same savegame file format as the flash version.

Comment: I think so because of the *.sav file type

Comment: *.sav is not a specific file format, there are dozens of different formats using the .sav file extension.

Comment: File extensions don't mean anything. They are a hint at the format, but they don't define it. I have seen a couple of programs and games which call their saved files ".sav" (in fact I used that extension for the savegames of one of my own games once), but internally these files still have completely different structures.

Comment: The chance of this being correct is the same as a save file from a completely different game working.  You have to store the data in the exact same way.